# Eigenvalue demonstration

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$Ax = λx$

How do you demonstrate that $(I+A)x = (λ+1)x$

I tried:

$(1+1/λ)Ax = (1+1/λ)λx$

$(1+1/λ)Ax = (λ+1)x$

$(IA+(1/λ)IA)x = (λ+1)x$

But that gives

$(A+(1/λ)A)x = (λ+1)x$

Comment: Just add $x$ to both sides.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(I+A)\mathbf{x} = \color{red}{I\mathbf{x}} + \color{blue}{A\mathbf{x}} = \color{red}{\mathbf{x}} + \color{blue}{\lambda \mathbf{x}} = (\lambda + 1)\mathbf{x}$.

Note that since $I$ is the identity matrix we get $I\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}$ and since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ we have $A\mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, we have $$Ax = \lambda x$$ $$\Leftrightarrow Ax + x = \lambda x + x$$ $$\Leftrightarrow Ax+I_n x = \lambda x + x$$ $$\Leftrightarrow (A+I_n)x = (\lambda + 1)x$$

where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.